# Hibernate SequenceStyleGenerator prefer_sequence_per_entity

Tags: hibernate, persistence, hibernate-4.x

I am working on a requirement where we need to use sequence per entity.

Right now I have created a table `hibernate_sequence` with columns and values as below:

```
next_value | sequence_name
-----------|--------------
 100000045 | 
 100050000 | ACCOUNT_SEQ
```

Following is my `hbm.xml` file for entity `ACCOUNT`:

```
<generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator"> 
            <param name="prefer_sequence_per_entity">true</param> 
            <param name="optimizer">none</param>
            <param name="increment_size">1</param> 
</generator>
```

But somehow my inserts using global sequence id instead of using sequence defined for ACCOUNT. Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong here?

I did refer [Steve answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737092/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-choose-a-generatedvalue-strategy-using-jpa-annota/12738227#12738227), but hibernate documentation is not clear on how to use this feature. Should we have a separate table for each entity (or) same table with different rows per each entity with some well-defined syntax?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?  Specifically, is 'prefer_sequence_per_entity' supported in the version you are using?

Comment: @SteveEbersole: I am using hibernate 4.0. I couldn't find "prefer_sequence_per_entity" in hibernate documentation. Is this available? If so, can you share link to documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'prefer_sequence_per_entity' was not added until 4.1.3 (see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6790).  Above you clarified that you are using 4.0.  You'll need to upgrade to use that, or copy over the 4.1.3 version of SequenceStyleGenerator