# Why doesn't Hibernate use the H2 DB's sequence?

Tags: hibernate, sequence, h2

I am using Hibernate 5.2.15 and a H2 database (version 1..4.197). I have created a sequence with

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_PRIMARYKEY START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

and my entity looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Payment", 
   uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"ID"})})
public class Payment {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_PK",sequenceName="SEQ_PRIMARYKEY")        
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq_PK")      
    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false, unique=true, length=11)
    private int id;
...
}
```

The DAO is implemented as follows

```
@Override
public void persist(T entity) {
    currentSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
    currentSession.save(entity);
    currentTransaction.commit();
    currentSession.close();
}
```

In the databse the current value of the sequence is for example 190, but when is persist an entity the id is 78.
I expect the ID to match the next value of the sequence. Is my expectation wrong? 
How do I need to change the implementation to meet my expectation?

Edit: When stopping Tomcat, I get the following warning:

```
WARNUNG: The web application [myApp] appears to have started a thread named    [pool-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a   memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos   (Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Maybe it is somehow related?

Edit2: After dropping the table and the sequence, now it seems to be in sync, but it might be a happy accident only. Although the sequence should start with 1 the first enitiy, which I have persisted got the ID "-46", instead of 1, which I would have expected. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228150/hibernate-5-sequencegenerator-not-giving-the-right-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745751/hibernate-sequencegenerator-and-allocationsize) are very similar to mine and setting the property allocationSize=1 solved my issue. On the other hand setting `<property value="true" name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings"/>` had no effect.