# ORA-02298 after migration to Spring Boot 2

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, migration, oracle12c

After migration to Spring Boot 2, this  behavior occurred when application boot. When startup is over application runs (does not fail during boot). Then I can change old records but can't add or delete any records from any table in db. This behavior is not a random, occurred during every boot.

I tried to find `CONSTRAINT 'FK84W6N01RUR44HH0WMBQQ8JYTC'`. By followed query

```
SELECT *  FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_NAME Like 'FK84%';
```

but it does not exist.

I don't know where Hibernate found this reference.

### Console output

```
  org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02298: (testDB.FK84W6N01RUR44HH0WMBQQ8JYTC) kann nicht validiert werden - übergeordnete Schlüssel nicht gefunden

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:213) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:37) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:896) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1737) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1692) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:300) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-02298: (testDB.FK84W6N01RUR44HH0WMBQQ8JYTC) kann nicht validiert werden - übergeordnete Schlüssel nicht gefunden

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Comment: execute SELECT *  FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS where OWNER = 'testDB';

Comment: I did it but the CONSTRAINT is not found in the result list.

Comment: do you have any auto ddl generation of Hibernate?

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update , yes ddl generation is used

Answer (score 0):

When you query

```
SELECT *  FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_NAME Like 'FK84%';
```

You will return nothing, because Hibernate tried to create constraint by Java code, put it into Oracle database management system. But it has error, therefore foreign key `FK84W6N01RUR44HH0WMBQQ8JYTC` is not exist. Foreign key field cannot find its corresponding primary key) It is error code `ORA-02298`.

Even if your constraint are correct, I guess that it still has chance to cause error if the sequence of Hibernate creating database order is not suitable: create field of foreign key before create table what has referenced primary key.

Solution: In `application.properties`, set

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Before app was migrated was used Spring Boot 1.5.x and entities used this generation

> @GeneratedValue

During migration to Spring Boot 2.0.2 was it changed into

> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

This perfectly works for new installation but for older installation with origin database occurred mentioned error. The solution seems to me is used auto generation

> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

[Mappings: Problems with GenerationType.AUTO in Hibernate 5](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-things-you-need-to-know-when-using-hibernate-with-mysql/)

After I solved problem with Oracle, new problem came up. Finally I did this.
[this was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228150/hibernate-5-sequencegenerator-not-giving-the-right-value)