# Table 'acme_ms.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

We are trying to migrate our microservice to **Spring Boot 2**, currently, we are using **Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE**.

During the migration process we recognized that our microservice is partially broken, in the log files we found the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'acme_ms.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist

Only one domain class exists in our application at the moment:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "acme_ms_card_details")
public class CardDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String cardType;
}
```

and we found that the issue related to `GeneratedValue` strategy type, we tried to change strategy to `GenerationType.IDENTITY` and the error disappeared.

So, the question that we have for now:
Why with Spring boot 1.5 `GenerationType.AUTO` works perfectly well but after migration to Spring boot 2, `GenerationType.AUTO` doesn't work at all.

What was critically changed?

Note: as a Database, we are using MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.5.6 uses Hibernate 5.0.12.Final while Spring Boot 2 uses Hibernate 5.2.12.Final and that new Hibernate version has a change which breaks `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO`.

You need to add the following property `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` to `true` to restore backwards compatibility.

[hibernate 5 sequencegenerator not giving the right value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228150/hibernate-5-sequencegenerator-not-giving-the-right-value)

Comment: also found this article: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-things-you-need-to-know-when-using-hibernate-with-mysql/ where the author advises to define @GenericGenerator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.