# How to set hibernate @GeneratedValue strategy dynamically in spring boot application?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-annotations

I have an spring boot applicaion that should be run on mysql in development environment and on sql server on production environment.
so i want to set `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` when application is running with `prod` profile and set to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` when application is running with `dev` profile.

I have `BaseEntity` class that all of the entities are extended from it:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // how to chagne this dynamically?
    private T id;

}
```

So how can i implement this requirement? should i change `.yml` files or implements some class and change some configurations to achieve this goal?

**UPDATE**

I don't want to use `sequence` for both SQL Server and MYSQL, i want to use `identity` feature of sql server, and sequence in mysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to dynamically choose a @GeneratedValue strategy using JPA annotations and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737092/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-choose-a-generatedvalue-strategy-using-jpa-annota)

Comment: No, please check my update

Comment: That's not possible